KeyError: 'temperature' in DSPy ChainOfThought()
I created a custom LM Client class like this
from dsp import LM
import json

class CustomLMClient(LM):
    def __init__(self, model, **kwargs):
        self.model = model
        self.provider = "default"
        self.history = []
        self.llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name=self.model)
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def basic_request(self, prompt: str, **kwargs):
        response = self.llm.invoke(prompt)
        response = response.json()

        self.history.append({
            "prompt": prompt,
            "response": response,
            "kwargs": kwargs,
        })
        return response

    def __call__(self,  prompt, only_completed=True, return_sorted=False, **kwargs):
        response = self.request(prompt, **kwargs)
        response = json.loads(response)
        completions = response["content"]        
        return [completions]


I instantiated and configured this LM with DSPy settings:
custom_lm_client = CustomLMClient(model = 'gpt-4-32k')
dspy.settings.configure(lm = custom_lm_client)

But when I try to use ChainOfThought:
# Define a module (ChainOfThought) and assign it a signature (return an answer, given a question).
qa = dspy.ChainOfThought('question -> answer')

# Run with the default LM configured with `dspy.configure` above.
response = qa(question="How many floors are in the castle David Gregory inherited?")
print(response.answer)

I get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[189], line 5
      2 qa = dspy.ChainOfThought('question -> answer')
      4 # Run with the default LM configured with `dspy.configure` above.
----> 5 response = qa(question="How many floors are in the castle David Gregory inherited?", temperature =0)
      6 print(response.answer)

File ~/Documents/Workspace/Autogen/pyautogen/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dspy/predict/predict.py:61, in Predict.__call__(self, **kwargs)
     60 def __call__(self, **kwargs):
---> 61     return self.forward(**kwargs)

File ~/Documents/Workspace/Autogen/pyautogen/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dspy/predict/chain_of_thought.py:59, in ChainOfThought.forward(self, **kwargs)
     57     signature = new_signature
     58     # template = dsp.Template(self.signature.instructions, **new_signature)
---> 59 return super().forward(signature=signature, **kwargs)

File ~/Documents/Workspace/Autogen/pyautogen/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dspy/predict/predict.py:76, in Predict.forward(self, **kwargs)
     74 # If temperature is 0.0 but its n > 1, set temperature to 0.7.
     75 temperature = config.get("temperature")
---> 76 temperature = lm.kwargs["temperature"] if temperature is None else temperature
     78 num_generations = config.get("n")
     79 if num_generations is None:

KeyError: 'temperature'

I tried to change the arguments of the basic_request and the init function but I get the same error. What do I change in the CustomLMClient class? to resolve the error

You could try to set temperature in the configure call, meaning dspy.settings.configure(lm=custom_lm_client, temperature=0.7)

You could try to set temperature in the configure call, meaning dspy.settings.configure(lm=custom_lm_client, temperature=0.7)
